# How to save an image in Windows Phone 8.1 using WinJS

Tags: javascript, image, windows-8, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking to migrate my Windows 8 app to Windows Phone 8.1 using WinJS. I had used `picker.pickSaveFileAsync` in Windows 8 which is not supported for WP 8.1.

I had then referred the official samples from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0

The Javascript version in the sample does not save on Windows Phone 8.1 when the Save As button is clicked and it returns the below error when `getFileAsync is called:

> 0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error

When clicked on Save, it returns a Read Only error. I had tested the sample in Lumia 520 also. I get the same error in the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone you cannot get write access to files returned from a FileOpenPicker. You have to use a FileSavePicker to do this. With the help of a coworker I was able to get a sample working that can open and then re-save a file under a new name starting from the "Blank" Windows Phone App template

Inside of your default.html create two buttons:

```
<button id="choose">Choose a Photo</button>
<button id="save">Save a Photo</button>
```

Replace default.js with the following:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var origFile = null;

    function pickPhoto() {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        var enumerator = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.getDecoderInformationEnumerator();
        enumerator.forEach(function (decoderInfo) {
            decoderInfo.fileExtensions.forEach(function (fileExtension) {
                picker.fileTypeFilter.append(fileExtension);
            });
        });
        picker.pickSingleFileAndContinue();
    }

    function loadPhoto(file) {
        origFile = file;
    }

    function savePhotoPicker(file) {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
        picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("JPEG file", [".jpg"]);
        picker.pickSaveFileAndContinue();
    }

    function savePhoto(src, dest) {
        src.copyAndReplaceAsync(dest).done(function () {
            console.log("success");
        })
    }

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());

            document.getElementById("choose").addEventListener("click", pickPhoto);
            document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", savePhotoPicker);
        }
        if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.pickFileContinuation) {
            loadPhoto(args.detail.files[0]);
        }
        if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.pickSaveFileContinuation) {
            savePhoto(origFile, args.detail.file);
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };

    app.start();
})();
```

If you are creating the file yourself, make sure to set the [ImageProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.imageproperties.aspx) for it before saving.

Sorry about the broken sample, I'll get that reported to the sample owner.

Comment: That couldn't fix the problem as it was still failing. But I have found an alternate way to save the images. Thanks for your help.